# Why do I get different results for complex multiplication involving NaN with gcc depending on optimisation level?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, complex-numbers, compiler-bug

Consider the following code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    complex double A = CMPLX(-NAN, 0.0);
    complex double B = CMPLX(NAN, 0.0);

    printf("A = %e %e, B = %e %e\n", creal(A), cimag(A), creal(B), cimag(B));

    B += 0.5 * A;

    printf("A = %e %e, B = %e %e\n", creal(A), cimag(A), creal(B), cimag(B));
}
```

on various amd64 Debian systems with gcc 8.5.0, 10.2.1 and gcc 12, this code produces the following output:

### output with no optimisation

```
# cc -o test test.c -lm && ./test
A = -nan 0.000000e+00, B = nan 0.000000e+00
A = -nan 0.000000e+00, B = nan 0.000000e+00
```

### output with -O1

```
# cc -O1 -o test test.c -lm && ./test
A = -nan 0.000000e+00, B = nan 0.000000e+00
A = -nan 0.000000e+00, B = -nan 0.000000e+00
```

I do not understand why the output differs.  On FreeBSD, I was unable to ever get the “-O1” output.  Instead, all versions of gcc I tested with all compiler flags always produced the “no optimisation” output.

Why does the output differ depending on optimisation flags?  Is this a compiler bug or perhaps undefined beahviour?  What can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: Hm... the compilation failed on MSVC (not the question) but it also failed on Godbolt which uses gcc.

Comment: @WeatherVane It works for me when I select “C” for the programming language.

Comment: Uh, yes I just saw that. The MSVC failed on `_complex` *[sic]* and `CMPLX`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Microsoft C doesn't support C99 complex numbers.

Comment: @Shawn it doesn't object to `#include <complex.h>` although it has warnings and errors about the arguments to `printf`. I do see though, the C standard mentions a macro `CMPLX`.

Comment: IEEE 754 does not specify the sign bit of `-NAN` (and therefore, neither does C). The only requirement is that the result be "a NaN", which it is. If there is more than one possible valid result of a floating point operation, the compiler can choose code which results in any of them; also (and probably relevant to your experiment), if it does the computation at compile time, it's free to choose a different result than the same computation done on the target machine (as long as both results are valid).

Comment: @rici So separate invocations of the `NAN` macro are not required to yield the same NAN?  In the real world code this is derived from the values were the result of computations, not the `NAN` macro.

Comment: That's correct. An invocation of the NAN macro can produce *any* quiet NAN; if the compiler happens to have one at its disposal, it's free to use it. And any computation which produces a NAN can produce *any* NAN, with the same observation about the compiler (particularly relevant for constant folding). Would an answer to that effect be useful?

Comment: Although I don't think the compiler is modifying the result of the NAN macro here. Where you see the difference is the computation of `.5*-NAN`, and that computation is not guaranteed to have any particular sign.

Comment: @WeatherVane see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/complex-math-support?view=msvc-170 (to clarify my earlier comment, it doesn't support C99 complex number *types*; though these days it does include its own non-standard complex number types and functions with C99 names to operate on them)

Comment: @Shawn the page you linked says "including all of the ones required by ISO C99". I've never used C complex types: only implemented myself – such as in fractal image rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEEE 754 does not specify the sign bit of the expression `-NAN` (or of any computation whatsoever involving a NAN). The only requirement C places on the macro `NAN` is that the result be a constant expression whose value is a quiet NaN. As far as I can see, nothing even guarantees that the precise NaN bit pattern produced be the same for every invocation of `NAN`.

According to IEEE-754, operations which propagate a NaN (like `.5*-NAN`) are required to propagate the NaN's *payload* (which comprises the mantissa after the first bit). But they are not required to propagate the sign bit; the operation may or may not follow the usual convention for sign bits.

In general, not only for NaNs, if there is more than one valid result from a computation, the C standard does not oblige compilers to choose the same valid result for every computation. There are cases where an intermediate result can legitimately be computed with precision beyond that of the datatype used, which can change the rounded value of the final result. Similarly, if there are two or more different NaN bit patterns which can result from an operation, the compiler is not obliged to arrange to be consistent. For example, the sum of two NaNs is a NaN, and the propagated payload requirement of IEEE-754 requires that the payload of the result be one of the payloads of the inputs. But it doesn't specify which one, so if the compiler happens to sometimes compute `A+B` and other times `B+A`, and those propagate different payloads, that's valid.

In particular, the compiler is free to fold constant computations at compile-time, and compile-time computations are not required to be bitwise identical with the actual computation which might have otherwise been emitted had the compiler not folded the constant. (Of course, they must be correct. But sometimes there is more than one correct bit-pattern.) I'm pretty sure that's what is happening here: GCC folds constants more aggressively at -O1 than at -O0. (Contrast that with Clang.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately I did not pay enough attention reducing this example.  In the real code, the NAN is the result of some numerical computations and thus not subject to these rules.  I'll try to reduce our actual program to a test case that does not use the `NAN` macro and open another question about that.

Comment: @fuz: Yeah, I get that. But it is still the case, as I said at the beginning, that the sign of the NaN is not stable. So some legal reorderings (commutativity, for example) can result in NaNs of different signs.